# How can I generate include files with my build of the SFML 2.4.2 static libraries using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.2)?

Tags: static-libraries, visual-studio-2017, sfml

I am attempting to install SFML Version 2.4.2 for use with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2. According to the tutorial provided on the SFML website, "if there's no SFML package compiled for your version of Visual C++, you will have to build SFML yourself."

So, I downloaded the source code for SFML 2.4.2, generated a Visual Studio project using CMake (Version 3.8.2) following [another tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/compile-with-cmake.php) on the SFML website, and built the project. The static libraries seem to have compiled fine (I have yet to test them, but they are present), but there are no header files generated, not even an 'include' folder.

I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793098/compiling-sfml-for-visual-studio-2012-using-cmake) in another question about compiling SFML for an older version of Visual Studio, but in the version I am using the menu is worded differently, and the option (i think) I'm supposed to change has been depreciated.

The information provided by Microsoft in the prompt warning me about the depreciated option seemed to only discuss handling project dependencies, not which types of files are generated when the project is built.

Comment: Use the include folder from the sfml zip. It should just be SFML/include

Comment: Copying the include folder from the sfml archive resulted in a different error seemingly related to a compatibility issue with newer versions of Visual Studio and some of SFML dependencies. I'll update my progress after I troubleshoot the new issue.

Comment: I ended up just copying the include folder from the SFML zip archive. I've successfully built several projects. Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Include files aren't really generated, they are just referenced by your project so it can see the declarations needed for SFML.

What you want to do is build the "INSTALL" target, which will install the libraries and headers which you can then reference in your project

Comment: Also worth noting - I believe the 2015 binaries will be compatible with 2017, if you'd prefer to use them